# facing a problem in installing my Rocky linux

Tags: rocky-os

i try to install Rocky linux in my virtual machine, on text based mode so when i reach the destination step where i choose to partition my disk manually, then i switch to CLI where i partition my disk as following :
sda1 primary length 512M file system ext4 mount to /boot.
sda2 extended takes all the left space in the disk.
sda5 logical in sda2 take its all space.

then i encrypt the sda5 with luks, the i open and map it to sda5_crypt.
in the next i create physic volume sda5_crypt.
and i create volume group will-vg on pv sda5_crypt.

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuGPn.png)